# How to check if the mouse is inside actual map bounds in d3 geo?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, projection

I am trying to find if the mouse is inside the map bound in d3. I am using the map `projection.invert(d3.mouse(container))` method to find it.

It is working if properly within the bound. But the problem is, when I am moving the mouse outside of the actual bound, it is still giving me some coordinates (lat-long).

I have made a [demo](https://beta.observablehq.com/@abdul-alim/checking-if-the-mouse-is-on-the-map) in Observable.

Is there any way to know if I am moving the mouse outside of the map bounds?

Answer (score 2):

You could just set a simple flag to make sure you are on a path:

```
d3.select(img).selectAll('path')
  .on("mouseover", function() { mutable isOn = true; })
  .on("mouseout", function() { mutable isOn = false; });
```

Or just change your `mousemove` to act on the paths instead of the svg:

```
d3.select(img).selectAll('path').on("mousemove", function() {
  mutable inverse = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
  mouse.attr("transform", `translate(${projection(mutable inverse)})`);
});
```

Updated [observable](https://beta.observablehq.com/@larsenmtl/checking-if-the-mouse-is-on-the-map).

Comment: **I must use canvas with d3.geoContains([long, lat])**. For demonstration I have used SVG.